# Invalid Thread Access

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, swt, eclipse-rcp

The create View Control Class

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        //viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI| SWT.V_SCROLL);
        //viewer.setContentProvider(new ViewContentProvider());
        //viewer.setLabelProvider(new ViewLabelProvider());
        // Provide the input to the ContentProvider
        //viewer.setInput(new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"});
        //Display display=new Display();
        parent.getShell().setText("A dialog box with no buttons at all press 'ESC' to close");
        final Shell shell = new Shell(Display.getCurrent());
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        
                    }
                    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            shell.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void paintControl(PaintEvent event) {
                                    Rectangle rect = shell.getClientArea();
                                    event.gc.drawOval(0, 0, rect.width - 1, rect.height - 1);
                                }
                            });
                            Rectangle clientArea = shell.getClientArea();
                            shell.setBounds(clientArea.x + 10, clientArea.y + 10, 200, 200);
                            shell.open ();
                            while (!shell.isDisposed()) 
                            {
                                if (!Display.getCurrent().readAndDispatch()) 
                                    Display.getCurrent().sleep();
                            }
                            Display.getCurrent().dispose();
                            
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            
        }).start();
}
```

Can anyone explain how threading works in SWT graphics . It says invalid thread access . According to me there is a thread running and i am creating another thread, which is definitely wrong.So what is correct method. In which line default thread is being created.  
It also gives a widget disposed error. Why?

The following code has been created from the default view plugin and
[here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet245.java)

My aim is to create diagrams in my view itself not in a separate dialog box.
I have also attached the log file.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-02-23 12:47:18.520
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDevice(Display.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.removeFilter(Display.java:4065)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.cleanUp(PartRenderingEngine.java:1241)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$5(PartRenderingEngine.java:1237)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1166)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at swtdiagrams.Application.start(Application.java:20)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2015-02-23 12:47:18.535
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDevice(Display.java:745)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getActiveShell(Display.java:1469)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.getActiveWindow(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.updateActivePart(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.checkActivePart(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.checkActivePart(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider$1.partDeactivated(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService$4.run(PartService.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService.partDeactivated(PartService.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$17.run(WorkbenchPage.java:4823)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.firePartDeactivated(WorkbenchPage.java:4820)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$20(WorkbenchPage.java:4813)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partDeactivated(WorkbenchPage.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$4.run(PartServiceImpl.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartDeactivated(PartServiceImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.setPart(PartServiceImpl.java:205)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:160)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have studied a lot of Stackoverflow pages on the same issues but none of issues were similar to me(They never wanted to create diagrams on view). Whatever code you see is the result of all the SO suggestions. Many didnot even have answers just comments.

Please help.

*EDIT*
After the edits told by Greg I am getting .
[image: this]

Is there anyway i can print it on the view(by view i mean the whitespace and not next to it.)
Thanks.

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but it is not wise to add paint listeners to the shell again and again in an infinite loop!

Comment: Ask a new question showing your new code. There should be no problem drawing in the view

Comment: problem solved. Actually i was using a viewer which was taking that white space as soon as i removed viewer. voila it was gone. 
@isnot2bad  you mean to say the infinite loop of timeExecs is wrong? If yes what should be the alternate approach?

Comment: @SarasArya I don't know what you want your code to do, but it cannot be correct to add an infinite number of paint listeners to a shell. What do you think?

Comment: Your original code was adding a new paint listener on every loop.

Comment: @isnot2bad i changed my code to greg's answer.The code snippet shown above was from Eclipse FAQ. I am new to Eclipse RCP so i didn't know it not good practice and that content on Eclipse site could be wrong. Anyways +1 for pointing that out

Comment: @SarasArya I doubt, this code snippet is a 1:1 copy from eclipse FAQ. And even without any special knowledge about SWT, adding a listener in a loop smells.

Comment: @isnot2bad [see this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Why_do_I_get_an_invalid_thread_access_exception%3F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `dispose()` on the `Display` object - never do that in Eclipse plugins.

If you want to draw in the view area itself just use a `Canvas` control, something like:

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent)
{
  // Create control

  final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(parent, SWT.NONE);

  // Set up a single paint listener

  canvas.addPaintListener(... paint the canvas );

  // Schedule a redraw after 1000 milliseconds

  Display.getCurrent().timerExec(1000, new Runnable() {
     public void run()
     {
       if (!canvas.isDisposed())
        {
          canvas.redraw();

          Display.getCurrent().timerExec(1000, this);
        }
     }
  });     
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't i dispose. I don't have a theory is to why i should. It's just that it was given in many sample snippets. I thought it was a good practice. Can you explain the above?

Comment: There is only one Display in an SWT application and it is only disposed when the application stops (which Eclipse does for you).

Comment: thanks for the explanation @greg-449 , one more ques. i have read on stackoverflow posts that timerExec and asyncExec are similar which one should i use ?

Comment: timerExec delays by the given number of milliseconds before calling the run. asyncExec runs as some as possible

Comment: How do i call timerExec again to repeat ? can you share some light on it @greg-449