# How to read the contents of the eclipse editor while editing/typing in it?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an Eclipse plugin which is required to read the contents of the editor every minute. So I want a button to start this process and one to stop it. Since I am new to plugin development I tried to work my way around a template given in eclipse. But the runtime application crashes.

Since I am new to plugin development I tried to work my way around a template given in eclipse. But the runtime application crashes.

```
public class SampleHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    int filename=0; 

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        //IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
        for (int i=0; i<10;i++) {

            /*MessageDialog.openInformation(
                window.getShell(),
                "TestEditorReader",
                "Running in background"); */// function call to print in the window

            PrintWriter writer = null;

            try {
                writer = new PrintWriter(filename+"file.txt", "UTF-8");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            filename++;
            writer.println(getCurrentEditorContent()); // function call to store it in files
            writer.close();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie) {

            }
        }

        return null;


    }

    public String getCurrentEditorContent() {
        final IEditorPart editor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()
            .getActiveEditor();
        if (!(editor instanceof ITextEditor)) return null;
        ITextEditor ite = (ITextEditor)editor;
        IDocument doc = ite.getDocumentProvider().getDocument(ite.getEditorInput());
        return doc.get();
    }

}
```

Comment: What does 'crashes' actually mean? But note that you must **never** call `Thread.sleep(10000)` in the user interface thread - this will make the entire UI lock up. Use something like `Display.timerExec`

Comment: Thanks @greg-449, I am able to read from the editor without using the loop. I want to automatically extract the file every 10 seconds. I can type in the editor only once, and after that when I press the plugin button the entire application seems to get locked up.

Can you please tell me how to use Display.timerExec?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28671795/2670892)

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks a lot!!